# Why doesn't the function change it's argument?

Tags: python

```
def func(l):
    l = l + l
    return ()
lst = [22, 33, 13]
func(lst)
print(lst)
```

The output is `[22, 33, 13]`. Why is it not `[22, 33, 13, 22, 33, 13]`?

Comment: Try `return (l)`. You might also want `lst = func(lst)`.

Comment: It still gives the same output.

Comment: I don't need the output to be the concatenated one. I just need to know the reason as to why this code isn't showing the desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function you made the reference `l` point to a new list object `l + l`. The outside reference `lst` still points to the original list object.

If the function had instead modified the *list object* itself, by appending to it for example, you would see the effect after the function ended.

```
def func(l):
    l.append(42)
    print(l)
    return () # Not really needed.

lst = [22, 33, 13]
func(lst)
print(lst)
```

If you want to get the desired result, try using the list `extend` method.

```
def func(l):
    l.extend(l)

lst = [22, 33, 13]
func(lst)
print(lst) # prints [22, 33, 13, 22, 33, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def func(l):
    l = l + l
    return l  # return l from function space.
lst = [22, 33, 13]
lst = func(lst) # need to update lst
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters your function returns a `tuple`, an empty one. It does not do anything to the list you passed it.

In any case even if you fix your function to actually return the list, you would still have to assign in to something, like below:

```
def func(l):
    l = l + l
    return l

lst = [22, 33, 13]
new_lst  = func(lst)

print(lst)
print(new_lst)

>>[22, 33, 13]
>>[22, 33, 13, 22, 33, 13]
```

Comment: Would you please give a stepwise analysis of the original code? I understand what you are saying here, but that is not my question. I want to know why it is not concatenating the argument as such if we pass a list into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function, in the line `l = l + l`, you're **creating a new list `l` based on the list passed in as an argument** and **losing the reference to the old list passed in as an argument** in a single line.

You never modify the list outside the function (e.g. what could be done by using the `append` or `extend` method), and you never return the new list inside the function, so you don't see any changes after the function is done executing.